# Scroll a DIV to top when user scrolls to bottom of page; hide DIV when user scrolls back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scroll

I've got three DIVs right under each other along the flow of the document, and all except the first DIV is set to `display: none;`. Therefore the first DIV (main_content) is the only DIV of the three that's visible when the page loads.

I need a jQuery script that would allow the next DIV to appear, and scroll to the top of the viewport (for clarification, this increases the document height) when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page I also need the script to hide the newly appeared DIV when the user scrolls back up.

This is what I have to far; it works but there's some weird looping going on.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    showDiv();
});

function showDiv(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= (($(document).height())-10)){
        $("#main_content2").fadeIn(1000);
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($("#main_content2").offset().top - 88)}, 800);
        $(document).height('auto');
        $(window).height('auto');
    }else{
        $("#main_content2").fadeOut();
        $(document).height('auto');
        $(window).height('auto');
    }
}
```

Not sure if my question is clear to you guys but let me know and I'll try to word things a little better. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks for the reply freedom. But this is not what I was looking for. I do not want the next DIV to affix to the top. I want the next DIV to appear, and snap to the top when the user scrolls to the bottom of the document. After the DIV snaps to the top the user is able to scroll through it as he would normally until he reaches the bottom of that DIV and then next DIV (3rd) appears and snaps to the top. I apologize if I wasn't clear enough before.

Comment: Related: Have a look at [bootstrap's affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Comment: It was as a suggestion for related.   Your "snap to the top" statement isn't overly clear, which is what made me think of affix.  So: show 1 div, user scrolls, at bottom, 1st div hides, 2nd div appears and scroll position is reset to the top?   Doesn't sound very friendly UX as the users scroll bar will jump while they're "holding" it.

Comment: When div2 appears, div1 hides? or div2 sits under div3?  Are you creating an *infinite scroll* ?   If so, easier just to plonk div2+ at the bottom and not mess about with repositioning.

Comment: Close. The first DIV just scrolls up; no longer visible to user. Same applies when the third DIV shows up; the first, and second DIV just scrolls up and is no longer visible. Hope that makes sense. Let me explain a little better. Imagine all the DIVs are visible and you have one DIV under the other. You scroll to the bottom of the first DIV, and you see the top of the second DIV. Now, instead of the user having to scroll the second DIV to the top, I want to use jQuery to scroll it to the top for the user. Thanks very much for the reply.

Comment: Yeah, that's horrid.  Guess it's my opinion, but having the page JUMP around would give me motion sickness (no joke).  Hopefully someone else can provide what you want.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right. I still think it looks alright with the fadeIn though. Thanks for the reply.